# Counting objects based on multiple relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I've got three models;

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class UserProfile(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = OneToOneField(User, CASCADE)
    subscription = CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class Image(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    owner = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
```

I would like to count all Image objects where the owners subscription doesn't equal a string (eg 'free'). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [lookup that spans relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```py
image_count = Image.objects.exclude(owner__userprofile__subscription='free').count()
```